# ASP.NET MVC doesn't find view in area

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I request an action which is inside an area. Route is correct so debugger goes into the action. If I access RouteData property in the action, I see controller, action and area names (so area key is set). But during View rendering I get an exception telling that view can not be find (it searches only among root-level views, not inside area). But if I explicitly specify View name, it works.

So the question is how to make it work implicitly?

**Update1**
Here is a screenshot with RouteData in Watches in my project structure:
[image]

**Update2**
Here is the text of the exception:

> The view 'Battles' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/AdminBattles/Battles.aspx
>   ~/Views/AdminBattles/Battles.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Battles.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Battles.ascx ~/Views/AdminBattles/Battles.cshtml
>   ~/Views/AdminBattles/Battles.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Battles.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Battles.vbhtml

Comment: Can you post your route, your controller name and the path to your view?

Comment: That is a bad question with little detail to be able to answer. I will give downvote if not fixed.

Comment: Here is the url of the full-sized screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WDiwt.png

Comment: I had the same issue but I solved it by creating a custom view engine and defining the area's to look in.

Comment: @Phil, could you please tell about it in more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, it was my fault. I registered area routes calling `context.Routes.MapRoute()` instead of `context.MapRoute()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Idsa,

You may find that a similar question that I had today (which I figured out) may help:

[goin back to my 'routes' - issue with partialviews and areas??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866866/goin-back-to-my-routes-issue-with-partialviews-and-areas)

basically, in your views web.config file(s), reference the namespaces that directly relate to either the root or the areas portions of the site.

worked for me in a very similar error scenario.

**[edit]** - re the custom viewengine. just add the following class to your Models folder (with your own custom paths of course):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ABC.Web.Site.Areas.Administration.Models
{
    public class ABCViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    {
        private static readonly string[] NewPartialViewFormats = 
            new[] {
                    "~/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/Full/{0}.aspx",
                    "~/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/Partial/{0}.ascx"
                  };

        public ABCViewEngine()
        {
            base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

then add the following to your global.asax (Application_Start()):

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ABCViewEngine());
```

good luck..

Comment: Jim, Great Answer.  I've adapted your answer to be a little more dynamic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973000/adding-sub-directory-to-view-shared-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-and-calling-the-view/23018523#23018523

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a folder with the same name as your controller (without the Controller bit) underneath Views and put your view in there?

So, not:

```
Areas
    AreaName
        Views
            MyView.aspx
```

but...

```
Areas
    AreaName
        Views
            ControllerNameWithoutControllerOnTheEnd
                MyView.aspx
```

Comment: Yes, I created this folder. But you can check it out on the screenshot I put above

Answer (score 0):

Searches tend to take people here, so I'd like to shard another related item.

I've had issues where the **view won't be returned** due to an **unexpected miss-match of the overloaded method** I meant to be calling, and the actual **method signature match**.

For example, if you have Id as a string, then View("Something",id) will match the overload expecting a string ViewName and a string MasterName...

**Not:**

```
return View("Something",id);
```

My recommendation here is that it can be more clear, and fix this problem, if you provide the parameter names

**But Instead:**

```
return View(viewName:"Something", model: id);
```

These types of problems can happen also in HTML Helper methods, where you often just expect to be able to pass in your model, but if you model is just a string, you might be matching some other overload method signature. (For example, the Action link html helpers.)

Because of this, I recommend just specifying the parameter name, and avoiding the unexpected.  Heck, it might even make the expectation of your code just a little more clear.